# core data saving lots of images in iphone,,

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, core-data, nsdata

I am working on an app that deals with lots of photos.
For example a user can download an picture and store in his iPhone or take a photo using the camera and save it.

The database tool I use is `CoreData` and I am wondering which is the best way I can do?
Store the photos in core data directly or store their URL only and put the photos in a sterate folder? or there are some other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can either store the image in core data using NSData (not my prefered way).

Or

You can store the path to the image, and store the image in a folder (i think this way is optimized for bette performance)

Answer (score 2):

You can use core data's "Store in External Record File" feature. This is available under iOS 5 and above, and it will handle the saving and fetching the data from your external file. Do not save the data of the image on core data as a blog/transformable. Performance is not optimal.

Comment: If your core data is iCloud enable, where would those external record files go (on iCloud as well)?

Comment: The files will be a part of iCloud.